# vite base path doesnt respect dist-directory

Tags: vite

I am using vite purely as dev server with a backend server that does the file serving for me and has no connection to vite itself. My vite application lives under nested path. Thats why I set the base-url as specified in the config to '/my/path/'. This works well and everything is served correctly.

Once I run build, it creates a dist folder with a manifest file. My index HTML that is served by the backend server either includes the vite devserver in dev more or loads the main.ts as specified by the maninifest.json `{ "src/main.ts": { "file": "assets/main.b3ed3483.js", ...}}`. Therefore my index HTML looks somewhat like this:

```php
<?php if($dev): ?>
  <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>
  <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts"></script>
<?php else: ?>
<?php $entry = parseJson('dist/manifest.json'); /* pseudocode */ ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/path/dist/<?= $entry.css[0] ?>" />
  <script type="module" src="/my/path/dist/<?= $entry.file ?>"></script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Now, I have the problem, that whenever a module is imported, it tries to load it from `/my/path/assets` instead of `my/path/dist/assets`. I tried changing the basepath to `/my/path/dist/` but now obviously the path arent resolved in dev correctly. What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand the src paths in your script tags but I think this should work, though you might need to make some changes to make your src paths match.

- Option one: If you are using linux, I would create a symbolic link from `/my/path/` to`/dist/assets/` e.g. `ln -s -r ./dist/assets/ assets` (-s for symbolic link and -r for relative links). This will provide two paths to the same directory, one from /my/path/assets and one from /my/path/dist/assets/.
- Option two: use a relative base path i.e. set `base` in your vite config to `''`. Note: in vite 2.x there is an issue where if you have multiple entry points the asset path will be incorrect. There is a [fix merged for vite 3.0](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4517).